# My ex-girlfriend uses my Apple ID to log in to her iPad. Do I have to give her my Apple ID password to reset it?

Tags: apple-id

She asked me to give her my Apple ID password to log out. But I don't want to share my password. She said she need that password to log out the iPad.

Do I have to give her my password?  What else can she do?

Comment: **I would not give her the password!** Have her meet you in a public place with the device and you sign out.

Comment: Does this Apple ID have any apps, music, movies, TV or whatever that cost money, and she wants to keep on this iPad?

Comment: Is remote reset an option? https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2701?locale=en_US

Comment: Use 'Find my iPad', and do a remote wipe on it. No need to meet, and she doesn't need your password.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As discussed elsewhere in the answers, **it is generally not advisable to simply share your Apple ID password with others.**

Also, having **Two-factor authentication** enabled provides an extra layer of protection (by notifying you with location and device type of where the login is attempted), and makes any unintended login attempts moot.

### Alternative to Sharing Apple ID Password

Generally friends/family exchange Apple ID password to get access to purchased apps, music and movies. A much better alternative than sharing password is to use Family Sharing feature which allows purchased content to be shared.

For more information refer to the linked Family Sharing homepage and the Apple Support article:

- [Family Sharing - Apple](https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/)
- [Family Sharing - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201060)

Family Sharing is recommended, because unlike sharing password, it doesn't give unfettered access to your Apple account while letting you share what you may need to share.

---

Coming to the original question, **yes it's required to enter Apple ID password and sign out before resetting an iOS device**. This is done to discourage any unintended reset attempts. Additionally, Find My iPhone needs to be disabled too (if enabled) when resetting an iOS device.

- [Sign out of iCloud on your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, Apple TV, or Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT208242)

As very nicely and cautiously noted by [@SolarMike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355281/279727), sharing the password may be potentially dangerous unless you trust the person with it. It is advisable to get the iPad in person, enter the password, sign out and reset it yourself.

Once signed out, check if the device is removed from your account by going to iCloud settings on any one of your other iOS/macOS devices or by going to [iCloud website](https://www.icloud.com).

As a precautionary measure, you **should** also changed the password once your ex-girlfriend's device is removed successfully from your account.

Also, as discussed above, consider leveraging Family Sharing feature in future.

---

### Important Note

It's crucial to note on this occasion, that you enable **Two-factor authentication** (if not done so yet) for your Apple ID. It helps in tracking and identifying unintended login attempts using your Apple ID. Having Two-factor authentication requires someone with access to your password to approach you to get the code, thereby ensuring security of your account.

Any login attempt is notified to you on your trusted device(s) with information regarding device type and location where the login is attempted. For more details, refer to the Apple Support article:

- [Two-factor authentication for Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204915)

Comment: I voted for this - more info than my answer...

Comment: Alternatively, change the password and then change it back afterwards

Comment: @somebody so as soon as you give that or any password to your account - the other person can change it and you are now locked out... **Don't** do it...

Comment: I meant on top of doing it yourself

Comment: @somebody You may not be _able_ to do it yourself. Regardless of your plans to "change it back afterwards", how do you know you'll be _able_ to do that? That requires trust. The premise of the question is that trust is lacking.

Comment: @somebody let's hypothetically assume she **does** want to lock out the OP. So, you send your altered password to her (which makes no difference, it's still the active password for the account, and you should only be using passwords for one site at a time, so no need to change it for protection), and then what? You wait a bit and change it back? You have two outcomes: you are **too soon** and she texts/calls and says the password won't work; or you are **too late** and she changed the password on you. So your alternative adds ZERO safety, and it allows her complete, unrestricted access.

Comment: @Aethenosity i meant you do it yourself... it's easier using a temporary password than having to change it (i.e. remember a new one)

Comment: @somebody you do what yourself?

Comment: @somebody The problem isn't whether the password you share is your standard one or a temporary one. The problem is that whoever has the currently valid password can do with the account whatever they please, and you have no way of stopping them.

Comment: Thank you for the fair play of adding the Family sharing suggestion 1h after me adding a specific answer just for that, without any attribution, and thus invalidating my answer.

Comment: I would advise you to NOT set up Family Sharing. I think in your situation it would only complicate matters. Some information why can be found at http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2320215 <- Please note that this information is old (published in 2015), so some or all of the information may be untrue today.

Answer (score 72):

Don’t just give the password - that gives **full** access to your account - she could change the password on you... Make it that **you** enter the password and reset... Either meet or she sends you the iPad...

Answer (score 18):

The only way to do it is do it yourself. You need to log out, log out of iCloud, and turn off "Find My iPad". Then she can create her own AppleID and log in with it.

I'd recommend to make an appointment at an Apple Store where you both meet, then you will have someone there who (a) goes through the procedure without getting anything wrong (I can't quite guarantee that my instructions are 100% right), and (b) who can make sure that nobody does anything nefarious (like making sure all you do is entering the password, and making sure your AppleId is gone in the end), and who (c) can help her setting up her own AppleId.

Comment: The advice about the Apple Store is right on.  However, she cannot simply log you out and turn off "Find my iPad", otherwise, every thief would do that 60 seconds after they steal your iPad.

Answer (score 8):

TLDR: [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srvyi.jpg) why this matters.

Sharing the password is out of the question.   But first let's fully discuss the problem scope.

**An iPad needs an Apple Account**.  I gather you figured out you can't go far with an iPad without one.  Doing so also activates features like "Find My iPad" and iCloud storage and backup, which is free, so *why not?*   App and media purchases are bound to the *account* not the *device*, so you can take your apps/media with you when you change devices.

**Each human needs *their own* Apple Account**.   So when she buy media or "buys" free apps, they're on her account.  I gather she hasn't done much of that because there are password challenges for pay items, but still.

**But don't accidentally create two Apple accounts**.  Everyone I know has two, because of confusion when setting up a new device. Apple won't allow merging of accounts, and you don't want some purchases on one account and some on another.  *So she should try in advance to log into icloud.com with a web browser, with past emails.  If she definitely doesn't have an Apple account, she should set one up in advance.*

### Back up *her* data

Creating her own Apple account and having her iPad on that is a good thing. But she should be clear all her apps will disappear (she can just re-"buy" them), and created content *may* disappear.

Also, look in `Settings/Mail, Contacts, Calendars` to see where notes, contacts, and some data *actually lives*; if it says 'iCloud' she'll lose it, but she can set up a Gmail account and the Apple Store can help her move it there.  That will need to be done before she disconnects from your Apple ID.

[image]

*Uh-oh*.

### Do the switch

Then you need to get together with her and sign it out of your account and bind it to her [new?] account.  It may seem weird that you need to "sign in to sign out", but **that's an [anti-theft feature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365)**.  Part of resetting is unhooking "Find My iPad" from your account, something a thief would be very keen on doing obviously.  So Apple requires you to *prove you're you*, hence the need for your password.  This recently saved a friend's iPad (it was found with the Activation Lock on).

Doing this "at the Apple Store" gives you a better shot of getting help if you get stuck.

Comment: I can't vote down on this but I would, it is full of oppinion and story telling unrelated to the question at hand. Also, you are wrong about Apple encouraging you to create a new account. If you go to the Apple Store, they will pretty much force you to use your existing id and have now tied every thing from logging into you computer to watching Netflix require you to use your Apple ID. If they really wanted you to create an new id to make you buy stuff twice, it would pretty make everything they show a keynote not work.

Comment: @Joe Welcome to StackExchange.  This is a Q&A platform where answerers are invited to improve their answers; that is the purpose of comments and in fact, *that's what you just did*.  And I hear what you say and I improved the answer.  That's how the rest of StackExchange works; it's nowhere near as salty as SO.  I hope you see that a constructive comment goes much farther toward getting what you want.   Assuming, of course, you want to persuade.  I for one basically never downvote unless an answer is *dangerous*.

Answer (score 8):

**NO!**

You absolutely *do not* have to give her your Apple ID password to reset it. Normally, if you reset it from the device, yes, you do have to enter the Apple ID password to the Apple ID associated with the device, but you do not have to reset it from the device. If you have a computer running macOS (a MacBook, iMac, etc.) or a computer running Windows with iTunes installed, then the following method will not require you to enter your Apple ID password and will still completely destroy all data on the iPad. First, turn the iPad off (hold the lock button until a slider comes up on the screen; slide the slider). Then, once the device has shut down, hold the lock button and the home button simultaneously and continue holding not until the Apple logo appears, but until the recovery mode screen appears (it usually consists of a Lightning cable and an iTunes logo). Then, if you are using a Windows computer, install iTunes on it at [this](https://www.apple.com/lae/itunes/download/) link. Macs have it preinstalled. Plug in the iPad and near the top left corner, you'll see a button that looks like an iPad. If you don't see it at first, just give it a minute. It usually doesn't show up instantly. Once you find the button, click it. Then, in the menu that comes up, click "Restore iPad..." and follow the steps that appear on screen.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 5):

This is kinda speculative, but can you kick her ipad off your account through your apple ID?

I know when I go into my phone, there's an entry for my computer there (apple account, my devices) and an option to remove the computer from my account.  It doesn't require proximity or other access to the computer. And Nimeesh Neema mentions going into your account to check if her ipad's been removed [after getting it off].

So you might be able to log into your account, check your devices, and find an option to remove this device from your account.  I don't know what exactly it'll do to the ipad or what needs to be done to get in functional again, but if it somehow doesn't reset neatly she can take it to an apple store and figure it out. I suppose it's then her business to set up her own apple ID to get it working again.

Comment: I think you're right, you can do that, but it would be a rougher transition for her because of the inability to back up her data and do a smooth transition.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely do not give any personal password to anybody as the other fine answers state.

However, note that for the future, you should create unique accounts, and setup a Family group.

With the family group, must of the apps / media can be shared with a girlfriend.

I share it with my wife and my kid.